# DataContractSerializer deserialization of properties moved from derived class to base class

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

Using DCS I am trying to deserialize objects from XML where the object serialized is of type Child inheriting class Base where Child had some properties which were deserialized but were later moved to the class Base in code. Now these properties don't get deserialized:

Take a look at this XML:

```
<Base i:type="a:DirectoryEntry" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/pending.Core.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/pending.Core.Models.Directory">
    <Active>true</Active>
    <ContentType>DirectoryEntry</ContentType>
    <Created>2012-03-12T11:51:25.3401552+01:00</Created>
    <a:Location>location</a:Location>
    <a:OpenHours>opening</a:OpenHours>
</Base>
```

xmlns:a denotes the derived type name. This class used to hold those props. Now they were moved into Base class and they no longer get deserialized by DCS (properties are null after deserialization). I'm talking about the properties with a: in front of them (Location and OpenHours in this case).

We have a lot of these files holding data. What are my options to correctly deserialize those files with DCS?

*please note that [KnownType] attributes are in use both on Base and Child class*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to move properties back to the originating class and also leave them in the class that they were first moved to. It now gives the warning of `Property hides the inherited member...Use the new keyword if hiding was intended` but I can live with that because deserialization now works again we can move the data from one provider to another. I was unable to find any other solution and modification of all the serialized data files was not an option.

Comment: I hope you'll take a look at my answer...I think it can help you out of your predicament.

Answer (score 1):

When you moved the properties to the base class, they effectively moved to another XML namespace. The base class is probably defined at the namespace `pending.Core.Models`, while the derived class is defined at `pending.Core.Models.Directory` (I'm assuming you didn't specify anything in `Namespace` property of the `[DataContract]` attribute. So if you changed the namespace where the element should be, then the serializer won't be able to match it with the data you have. If you moved the last two properties to the base class, you'll then need to change the namespace of the XML elements `Location` and `OpenHours`.

```
<Base i:type="a:DirectoryEntry"
      xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/pending.Core.Models"
      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/pending.Core.Models.Directory">
  <Active>true</Active>
  <ContentType>DirectoryEntry</ContentType>
  <Created>2012-03-12T11:51:25.3401552+01:00</Created>
  <Location>location</Location>
  <OpenHours>opening</OpenHours>
</Base>
```

Comment: thanks, that is the obvious answer but requires manually changing the XML files. Do you know of an alternative that would make DCS find those properties in the Base class and serialize to them?

Comment: @mare both options are in this answer; either add the old namespace to the new DataContract using the Namespace property, or change the namespace specified in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by mare above - or below - in the accepted answer, there is no solution for not having the property in the original class. However, with the use of the `new` keyword in the property declaration in the original class, the warning can be disabled. I also ended up with the following structure:

```
[DataContract]
class Base
{
    [DataMember]
    public int X { get; set; }
} 

[DataContract]
class Derived : Base
{
    [DataMember]
    private new int X
    {
        get => base.X;
        set => base.X = value;
    }
}
```

The `DataContractSerializer` reads the property through reflection, so it does not really care about the property being private, but having the property in its original location private, prevents using it from code (as intended).